# Q: Does stictly increasing function always cross x and y axis?

Tags: functions, universal-property

I've been trying to figure out this problem:
Let *f*: be strictly increasing function on it's **Domain** with range of **all real numbers**.
Does it always intercept `x` and `y` axis ?



So my guess is that strictly increasing function with with  `range of all real numbers` always crosses both `x` and `y` axis.

Apparenty this my guess is wrong.


I can't figure out the right answer based on the theory that i found on the internet or in my textbook.


I've tried to graph different strictly incresing functions like: `f(x)= 2x-1`,  `f(x)= 2x+3`or `f(x)= x+3`.

They all seem to have both `x` and `y` intercepts.

I think the question has something to do with function `f(x) =x`


Thank you.

Comment: $x=0$ need not be in the domain of the function, in that case it would not cross the y-axis. And if the function has “range of all real numbers” then it must take the value zero somewhere, i.e. it crosses the x-axis.

Comment: The usage of "range" has changed over time. In older books, the "range" means what is called the "codomain" these days ( ie. the set of values the function may take but need to take). In modern books, the "range" means the "image" (ie. the set of values the function has taken). So the answer of your question depends on how old is the source of that question.

Comment: Thank you for your fast responses. Maybe the meaning of the question was little bit butchered in translation. But @MartinR was right, thanks.

Comment: Try plotting the function $f(x)=logx$ with some online graphing app to see that a function can be strictly increasing without having to cross the $y$ axis.

Comment: @user25406 Thank you for your answer, I did and it worked!!!. I think the problem I was having was that I for some reason thought that it was defined on all real numbers, therfore i did not think of logarithms.

Comment: @randomGuy, you can also have a function that never crosses the $x,y$ axis but is not strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Try graphing $f(x)=1/x$.